# Ruby elegant way to deal card array to player objects

Tags: ruby, arrays, iterator

I'm having trouble finding a nice elegant ruby way to do this. I have a *deck* array with 52 `Card` objects, and I want to iterate over it and loop through an array of `Player` objects, dealing one card at a time into their *hand* array. Something like:

```
deck = Card.deck.shuffle!
deck.each do |card|
    @players.NEXTELEMENT.hand << card
end
```

where `NEXTELEMENT` would yield the next element and return to the start of the array on encountering the end. I tried adding a method like this to Array, but I got a LocalJumpError.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just mod which card you are at by the number of players.

```
num_players = @players.size

deck.each_with_index do |card,index|
  @players[ index % num_players ].hand << card
end
```

Comment: Thanks, this way is very clean and similar to what i originally intended.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
deck.each_slice(@players.size) do |cardSet|
 @players.zip(cardSet).each {|player,card| player << card}
end
```

Comment: I just realized that there's no handling for running out of cards. You can pre-slice the deck to get an even number, or break early from the outer loop if you detect cardSet contains nil elements.

Comment: If you're using 1.9, you can say something like:
    break if cardSet.any?(&:nil?)

Comment: is there an easier way to do this if it doesn't need to be one by one?

Comment: cardCount = 7; @players.each {|player| player.push *deck.shift(cardCount)}